# How do I use CSS or PHP to customize Wordpress Form Manager Plugin Table?

Tags: php, css, table

I'm using **Wordpress Form Manager Plugin** to design a table to display race winners for an athletic event.

```
<table class="fm-data">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="fm-item-cell-lane">7</td>
<td class="fm-item-cell-bib">124</td>
<td class="fm-item-cell-fullname">Person Two</td>
<td class="fm-item-cell-country">USA</td>
<td class="fm-item-cell-sb">11.20</td>
<td class="fm-item-cell-pb">11.03</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to use the 3-letter country code together with some CSS and or PHP to dynamically display the country flag after the 3-letter code.

For more info on the limitations and functions of the plugin: [Form Manager's documentation](http://www.campbellhoffman.com/form-manager-faq/)

Any Suggestions?

Comment: That is a lot of reading. Can you narrow the problem down some?

Comment: Seems to me to be a CSS problem, not a WordPress problem. Maybe better to ask on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @s_ha_dum What I have currently is the following `
<td class="fm-item-cell-country">USA</td>` I would like to use some script to output the following where the country flag dynamically displays based on the 3-letter country code.`
<td class="fm-item-cell-country">USA <img src="countryflag.gif></td>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

many ways to do it, not best but easiest is problably javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">      
jQuery('.fm-item-cell-country:contains("USA")').addClass('americanflag');
</script>
```

from that you edit your css (which I guess you're more comfortable with),
setting property for each class (.americanflag in that case)

Hope that help a bit

Comment: There seems to be an error on line 3. After replacing the line 1 typo from srcipt to script there is still the error. I've created the css and still no luck.

Comment: don't copy it in function, but in your header for instance, remove the line starting with // , its just a comment. Still no class added?

Comment: Did all that. Still no luck. The table is still without the class. Is there another way that you had in mind?

Comment: Problem solved! By using your last suggestion and replacing **jQuery** with **$** and putting the script in my footer instead of my header, everything worked fine.  Thanks for the help. Final script was:    `<script type="text/javascript">      
$('.fm-item-cell-country:contains("USA")').addClass('usaflag');
</script>`  Thanks again.